# validate only last radio button of a group of radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

i have a form with questions, and need validate these questions, answered with radio buttons, this form have 20 or more questions, the questions have options 1,2,3. 1 = good, 2 = problem, 3 = critic. the user can check only 5 times the option 3. how i can do it with javascript?

i use only normal validate to unchecked options.

here a preview of radios:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8QSm/)

```
<div class="inline">
 <label for="option1">
  <input type="radio" name="group[1]" value="1">1</label>
 <label for="option1">
    <input type="radio" name="group[1]" value="1">2</label>      
 <label for="option1">
    <input type="radio" name="group[1]" value="1">3</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inline {
    display: inline;    
}

.inline label, input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
}

.inline label {
    display: block;
    background: #eee;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.inline input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please post the javascript code you have attempted to write yourself, as per the question guidelines in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `value="1"` in every radio was a typo and you meant

```
<label for="option1">
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="group[1]" value="1">1</label>
<label for="option2">
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="group[1]" value="2">2</label>      
<label for="option3">
<input type="radio" id="option3" name="group[1]" value="3">3</label>
```

Then you can find how many checked radios with value="3" are there using

```
jQuery('input[value="3"]:checked').length
```

and act accordingly if the length is greater than 5.

Edit: [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WB9Vw/1/) (with the limit set to 2, not 5).

Comment: thanks for your help, your script is what i looking for. i will study him and improve my javascript skills.